# Stage3D in Flash Player 11 doesn't display

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, viewport, mxmlc, stage3d

I'm trying to write a 3D game in ActionScript 3.0 using the Stage3D API. I've copied the `playerglobal.swc` in my `frameworks/libs/player/11.0` directory, and modified the `frameworks/flex-config.xml` file by changing the `target-player` to `11.0.0` and the `swf-version` to `13`.

When I compile my ActionScript 3.0 files using `mxmlc` I set the options `-target-player=11.0.0` and  `-static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true`. Now, I don't get an error at compile time when importing `com.adobe.utils.AGALMiniAssembler` or `flash.display.Stage3D` so I assume that there's no problem with that.

I run the compiled SWF file in Opera, and I'm using the latest Flash Player (version 11.0.1.152) which was publicly released today (cheers ;D). There's seems to be no problem with the player because I can play Zombie Tycoon. However, when I play my SWF file the Stage3D doesn't display; but all the other display objects attached to the stage do display.

I believe that there's either some problem with my configuration or my code, but I can't pinpoint it. The code I'm using was simply copied from [Labs @ Jam3](http://labs.jam3.ca/2011/03/molehill-getting-started/). I believe that there was some problem with the viewport, so I simply replaced `stage.stage3Ds[0].viewPort=new Rectangle(0, 0, 980, 570);` with `stage.stage3Ds[0].x=0; stage.stage3Ds[0].y=0;`. Perhaps, that's the cause of the problem.

I have been searching for a solution all over the web, but I can't seem to locate it. Any help will be appreciated. Note however that I don't wish to use frameworks like Away3D because I wish to use the low-level functionality (I'm more into programming). If you want any more details, please ask.

Comment: * Make sure you have the latest playerglobal.swc.

Comment: Also, if you view the flash movie in html you can check for the correct wmode parameter (http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html).

Comment: _@Miha_ - Thank you. Setting the `wmode` parameter to `direct` solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*@Miha* - Thank you for answering my question. I set the `wmode` parameter to `direct`, and it worked like a charm. Apparently, the Stage3D API doesn't work in `transparent`, `opaque`, or `window` mode. If anyone is having similar problems, here's my HTML code which solved the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"\>
    <title>Hello Stage3D!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <object width="800" height="600" data="HelloStage3D.swf">
      <param name="wmode" value="direct"/>
    </object>
  </body>
</html>
```

To use the Stage3D API, you have to set the `wmode` parameter to `direct`. Nothing else will work. Line 9 is necessary.